# Why so many files relating to grub (/etc/grub.d/, /etc/default/grub, /boot/grub2/grub.cfg)? What is the purpose of each?

Tags: boot, grub2

I have seen that grub2 configuration files exist in so many different locations.

1. `/etc/grub.d`
2. `/etc/default/grub`
3. `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Can anyone tell me the purpose of each directory/file?

Comment: I recently stumbled upon `/etc/default/grub.d`... Is it new? should I store settings into a file stored in this dir? doesn't seem to work, though...

Comment: The files in `/etc/default/grub.d` need to be named `.cfg`

Comment: "The files in /etc/default/grub.d need to be named .cfg". I don't think so!

Comment: and now I see in debian buster a new folder : `/etc/default/grub.d` !!!

Comment: See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/901600

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/etc/default/grub` is where you can set simple options for many GRUB settings. It is parsed as a shell script.

`/etc/grub.d` contains shell scripts which generate GRUB configuration (based on settings on `/etc/default/grub`). `update-grub` (aka [`grub-mkconfig`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/grub-mkconfig.8)) runs these scripts to generate actual GRUB configuration.

`/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` is where the generated configuration is saved for GRUB to use.

Ordinarily, for setting GRUB options, you edit `/etc/default/grub`. If you need to generate additional GRUB entries or alter the entries generated, then add or change scripts in `/etc/grub.d`. Don't manually edit `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.